# Can't create databases with a new user

Tags: mysql

I made a new user and from root I run the command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

But then when I want to create a new database from user USER it always says:

```
Acces denied for user 'USER'@'localhost' to database 'database_name'
```

I neved used databases, so can anyone help me on how to create a database ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```